# supply password in crosh (chrome os shell) ssh?

Tags: command-line, ssh, shell, google-chrome-os

I have a CR-48 and I'm attempting to connect to SSHdroid. I understand the standard command for connecting to SSH is `ssh root 192.168.2.bla` but how do you supply a password along with that command because it says `No route to host`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just type the password when you're asked for it.

"No route to host" is caused by an entirely different thing: your computer is not able to even *reach* the destination host over IP, much less make a SSH connection.

This exact message means there's no matching entry in the route table, and it'd be easy to check on a "normal" operating system, but I really cannot say more about Chrome OS. (Unless `crosh` happens to have `route` or `ip route` commands...)